# How can I store name/value pairs in a file with Ruby where the values can be also multiline text?

Tags: ruby, file, hash, name-value

How can I store name/value pairs (also called hashes) in a file with Ruby where the values can be also multiline text? Of course I want to code the most simple way. 
I have seen such text files earlier in Windows:

```
[name]
Dr. Hash Mark

[biografy]
Bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla

[works]
The big red one (1923)
The little black zero (1926)
```

Is there any library or gem for Ruby to handle this kind of files? Maybe I could use XML and the XMLSimple gem:

```
<man>
 <name>Dr. Hash Mark</name>
 <biografy>
  Bla bla bla
  bla bla bla
  bla bla bla
 </biografy>
 <works>
  The big red one (1923)
  The little black zero (1926)
 </works>
</man>
```

Both of them would be good for me, but I also need a handy application to fill in a bunch of this kind of text files with data, I have no clue which application to use to generate such text files which later will be readable with Ruby. I think of a relational database application  - but I am not sure - in which I can define my data structure (the name, biografy, works) and then I get text fields to fill in with data, and then save the data in the given format in text files. Can anybody help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

YAML is a good choice, there is a lib for it in the stdlib, it is human readable/editable, it's fairly widely used (e.g. settings files in Rails), it supports multiline strings:

```
require 'yaml'

filename = 'hash.yaml'
original_hash = {'a' => 'b', 'c' => "d\ne"}
File.write filename, YAML.dump(original_hash)

puts "FILE LOOKS LIKE: #{File.read filename}"
puts "-" * 10

resulting_hash = YAML.load File.read(filename)
puts "READ BACK IN: #{resulting_hash.inspect}"

puts "ARE THEY THE SAME? #{original_hash == resulting_hash}"
```

Comment: and a visual editor application which can export to YAML format?

Comment: I don't really know what that means, but YAML is a plain text format, and both of the text editors I use (vim and TextMate) will automatically recognize and highlight it when I open it (you'll probably have to configure this in vim if you haven't used it before).